# Angular2 & typescript get error with import

Tags: visual-studio, angular

I'm starting to implement a simple component based on angular 2 , but i get an issue `tsconfig.json` and `import`

Here is my structure

`Root
    |
    node_modules
    |          |
    |          @angular
    |                |
    |                Core
    |                platform-broswer-dynamic
    Script
          |
          Components
                    |
                    MyFirstComponent.ts
                    MyFirstComponentService.ts`

Here is my code

```js
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'; // this line is ok 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  // this line is ok 
import { FirstService } from 'Root/Script/Components/MyFirstComponentService'; // this line get error

@Component({
    selector: 'firstcomponent',
    template: '<div>My First Component</div>',
})
export class MyFirstComponent {
    constructor(public abc : FirstService)
    {
        console.log(abc.doSomething());
    }
}
bootstrap(MyFirstComponent, [FirstService]);
```

But i get error at

> import { ABCService } from 'Root/Script/Components/MyFirstComponent';

Because some reason i don't want to use `import { ABCService } from ./MyFirstComponent';`

What config should i use in `tsconfig.json` to make three `import` work ? i've tried with `rootDir` but it not help

I'm using VS2015 , typescript 1.8.32

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to specify the full path, the service and the component are both in the same file location so you will need to use `./` like so:

```
import { FirstService } from './MyFirstComponentService';
```

EDIT: Going by your comment, I THINK you're asking this. Say you have another sub folder inside your `Root`, and another sub folder inside your `Components`, so you have this now:

`Root
    |
    node_modules
    |          |
    |          @angular
    |                |
    |                Core
    |                platform-broswer-dynamic
    Script
         |
         Components
         |        |
         |        MyFirstComponent.ts
         |        MyFirstComponentService.ts
         |        |
         |        navbar
         |             |
         |             navbar.component.ts
         |             navbar.component.html
         |
         Shared
              |
              authservice.component.ts`

if you wanted to access the the `navbar.component` from inside that same file, you would use:

```
import { FirstService } from './navbar/navbar.component';
```

You would would need to specify that from the current folder, `./`, go to the navbar folder, then get the component there.

Now if you wanted to access the `authservice.component`, you would do the following:

```
import { FirstService } from '../Shared/authservice.component';
```

The reason for this is that the `Shared` folder is located one folder higher than the current folder you're in, that's why you would use `../`, this essentially takes you one folder "higher".

Does that explain it better? I just added random "common" components. Also maybe consider changing your folder structure, and naming your folder/components as lower case only.

Comment: But for some reasons  i don't want to use `import { ABCService } from ./MyFirstComponent` , what i need is full path . Do you have any solution for this ? thanks you

Comment: @Trada I updated my answer, is this what you're looking to understand?

Answer (score 0):

use ./MyFirstComponent in place of that full path.. it work fine with that

Comment: But for some reasons  i don't want to use `import { ABCService } from ./MyFirstComponent` , what i need is full path . Do you have any solution for this ? thanks you